# Where can we find the preference names(Keys) that we use in Chrome capabilities in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

To set user profile to Selenium Drivers, we use capabilities.

```
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();    
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
co.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
```

Where can we find the names of these preferences i.e., `profile.default_content_settings.popups, download.default_directory`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it in [chromium.googlesource](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/pref_names.cc)

`download.default_directory` will look like

```
const char kDownloadDefaultDirectory[] = "download.default_directory";
```